# JRoute not return specific menu item link

Tags: custom-component, jroute

i have developing a custom component. i have a problem:

i am in a menu that show view 1. when i use `JRoute` function for link to view2 that have specific menu item, it return current url and add `?view=view2` at end of it. but i want it link to specific url.

my router.php file that may be help:

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class ANEductionSystemRouter implements JComponentRouterInterface
{

    public function build(&$query)
    {
        $segments = array();
        if (isset($query['view'])) {
            switch ($query['view']) {
                case 'course':
                    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
                    $qry = $db->getQuery(true);
                    $qry->select('customid,alias');
                    $qry->from('#__aneductionsystem_courses');
                    $qry->where('id = ' . $db->quote($query['id']));
                    $db->setQuery($qry);
                    $result = $db->loadObject();
                    $segments[] = $result->customid . '-' . $result->alias;
                    break;
                case 'teachers':
                    if (isset($query['id'])) {
                        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
                        $qry = $db->getQuery(true);
                        $qry->select('alias');
                        $qry->from('#__aneductionsystem_teacher');
                        $qry->where('id = ' . $db->quote($query['id']));
                        $db->setQuery($qry);
                        $alias = $db->loadResult();
                        $segments[] = $alias;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
//                throw new Exception(JText::_('JERROR_LAYOUT_PAGE_NOT_FOUND'), 404);
                    break;
            }
        }
        unset($query['view']);
        unset($query['id']);
        return $segments;
    }

    public function parse(&$segments)
    {
        $menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();
        $menuInfo = $menu->getActive();
        $view = $menuInfo->query['view'];
        $id = $tpl = null;
        switch ($view) {
            case 'teachers':
                $vars = array();
                $db = JFactory::getDbo();
                $qry = $db->getQuery(true);
                $qry->select('id');
                $qry->from('#__aneductionsystem_teacher');
                $qry->where('alias = ' . $db->quote($segments[0]));
                $db->setQuery($qry);
                $id = $db->loadResult();
                $view = 'teachers';
                break;
            case 'profile':
                $vars = array();
                switch ($segments[0]) {
                    case 'complete':
                        $id = 0;
                        $view = 'profile';
                        $vars['tpl'] = $segments[0];
                        break;
                    case 'subscribes':
                        if (isset($segments[1])) {
                            $id = $segments[1];
                            if (isset($segments[2])) {
                                $vars['action'] = $segments[2];
                                if($vars['action']=='sendBank') {
                                    if (isset($segments[3]) && is_numeric($segments[3])) {
                                        $vars['invoiceId'] = $segments[3];
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } else
                            $id = 0;
                        $view = 'profile';
                        $vars['tpl'] = $segments[0];
                        break;
                    case 'purchases':
                        if (isset($segments[1]))
                            $id = $segments[1];
                        else
                            $id = 0;
                        $view = 'profile';
                        $vars['tpl'] = $segments[0];
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new Exception(JText::_('JERROR_LAYOUT_PAGE_NOT_FOUND'), 404);
                }
                break;
            case 'headlines':
                $vars = array();
                $db = JFactory::getDbo();
                $qry = $db->getQuery(true);
                $qry->select('id');
                $qry->from('#__aneductionsystem_lessons');
                $qry->where('alias = ' . $db->quote($segments[0]));
                $db->setQuery($qry);
                $id = $db->loadResult();
                $view = 'headlines';
                break;
            case 'courselist':
                $tmp = explode('-', $segments[0],2);
                $cid = $tmp[0];
                $alias = $tmp[1];
                try {
                    $vars = array();
                    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
                    $qry = $db->getQuery(true);
                    $qry->select('id');
                    $qry->from('#__aneductionsystem_courses');
                    $qry->where('customid = ' . $db->quote($cid));
                    $qry->where('alias = ' . $db->quote($alias));
                    $qry->where('published = 1');
                    $db->setQuery($qry);
                    $id = $db->loadResult();
                    if (isset($segments[1]) && $segments[1] == 'subscribe')
                        $view = 'subscribe';
                    else
                        $view = 'course';
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    throw new Exception(JText::_('JERROR_LAYOUT_PAGE_NOT_FOUND'), 404);
                }
                break;
            case 'ajax':
            case 'login':
                return array('view' => $view, 'segments' => $segments);
                break;
            default:
//                throw new Exception(JText::_('JERROR_LAYOUT_PAGE_NOT_FOUND'), 404);
                break;
        }

        if (!empty($view) && isset($id)) {
            $vars['view'] = $view;
            $vars['id'] = $id;
        } else {
            throw new Exception(JText::_('JERROR_LAYOUT_PAGE_NOT_FOUND'), 404);
        }
        return $vars;
    }

    public function preprocess($query)
    {
        return $query;
    }
}
```

thanks for your answers.

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Please take our [tour]. What is the current result of your script?  Any errors?

Comment: @mickmackusa no i haven't any error. but when i use this function in view1 to link to view2, instead of link to specific view2 menu item, this function return current page url + ?view=view2 at end

Comment: Can you show us some of the diagnostic work that you have done?  Can you verify that the variables that you are attempting to populate _actually_ have the expected values in them?  Isolating the point(s) of failure will surely help us to navigate your code and more swiftly identify the part(s) that are breaking.  Please edit your question to show what each relevant variable holds.

Comment: @mickmackusa hi, JRoute function is work currectly in all arround site, but it still when i am in a view of component and i want get SEF link to another view. i haven't any error log and error reporting is maximum, so all used variables are defined.

Comment: Can you show us your JRoute::_ call? Are you passing Itemid within the URL? If so, have you tried removing Itemid from it?

Comment: no i don't send item id. item id is menu id? or another?